# How to assign the values of the nested dictionary to separate variables in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, assign

```
df_dict = {
    b'A': {'lo': 31.610000610351562, 'hi': 32.25}, 
    b'AA': {'lo': 32.810001373291016, 'hi': 34.040000915527344}, 
    b'AA/PR': {'lo': 76.75, 'hi': 76.75}, 
    b'AAA': {'lo': 60.31999969482422, 'hi': 60.64820098876953}
}

for ticker in df_dict:
    print(ticker)
    for price in df_dict[ticker]:
        print(df_dict[ticker][price])
```

**Output**

```
A
31.6100006104
32.25
AA
32.8100013733
34.0400009155
AAA
60.3199996948
60.6482009888
AA/PR
76.75
76.75
```

The output of the above is:
Ticker
'lo' value
'hi' value

I want to assign 'lo' and 'hi' values to two variables and calculate their ratio.

The above code is where I am at, and I am stuck there.

Comment: Could you be more concise regarding what's your desired output is?

Comment: dont use loop in `df_dict[ticker]`...just assign their value in variables i.e. `lo = df_dict[ticker]['lo']`

Comment: do you really need to assign `lo` and `hi` values to variables? you can calculate ratio without using variables

Comment: If we consider A ticker, I want to calculate 31.6100006104/32.25 (and see if it is less than, let's say, 10% or more than 1000% as a ratio (outside of the range of 0.1, 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to access the `'lo'` and `'hi'` keys and assign the values to the variables. Then you can calculate the ratio.

```
for ticker in df_dict:
    lo, hi = df_dict[ticker]['lo'], df_dict[ticker]['hi']
    print('Ratio:', lo / hi)
```